# Class path of 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found

Tags: laravel-5

This is my Product Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class ProductController extends Controller
  {
    public function index(){

    }
    public function create(){
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        // validate the form
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'image'=>'image|required'
        ]);
        // upload the image
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image=$request->image;
            $image->move('uploads',$image->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        // save the data into database
        Product::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'price'=>$request->price,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'image'=>$request->image->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);

        // session message
        $request->session()->flash('msg','Your Product has been added');
        // redirect
        return redirect('products/create');
    }
```

[I am not able to upload and save data on mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAjCu.png)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Product::create()` that means you're using model, so you must include Product model with `use App\Product;`